# Java8 stream filter by multiple parameters

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following class:

```
public class Transfer {
    private String fromAccountID;
    private String toAccountID;
    private double amount;
}
```

and a `List` of `Transfer`s:

```
....
private List<Transfer> transfers = new ArrayList<>();
```

I know how to get one transfer history:

```
transfers.stream().filter(transfer -> 
    transfer.getFromAccountID().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
```

But I want to get by `fromAccountID` and `toAccountID`, so the result will be a `List` of `Transfer`s. How can I do that with Java8 `Stream` filter functions?

Comment: you should never call `get()` straight from an optional result except in cases where you know there will be a value present. rather you should utilise [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) or [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) depending on which is most appropriate for your case

Comment: your advise was really helpful today, get() threw an exception, in order to handle it, I've used orElse and check it if it is null. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

filter by the two properties and collect into a list.

```
List<Transfer> resultSet = 
      transfers.stream().filter(t -> id.equals(t.getFromAccountID()) || 
                        id.equals(t.toAccountID()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `filter` by both properties (`getFromAccountID()` and `getToAccountID()`), and `collect` the elements that pass the `filter` to a `List`:

```
List<Transfer> filtered = 
    transfers.stream()
             .filter(t -> t.getFromAccountID().equals(id) || t.getToAccountID().equals(id))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```